# Catching SQLExceptions with Java and React

Tags: reactjs, oracle, spring-boot, exception, sqlexception

I have an app with a React frontend, Spring Boot backend and Oracle DB. I made a trigger which raises a custom exception with a custom number. For some reason I can't display its message in React - only that request failed with status code 500. How do I do it? For some reason when I try to add an SQLException to a catch block it says it cannot be thrown from anywhere.
DaoImpl:

```
@Override
    public void delete(Integer id) {
        SqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("ID_SETTINGS", id);
        try {
            namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(DELETE_SQL, parameters);
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException("Error during deletion: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        log.info("Request for delete settings {}", id);
        Settings settings = settingsService.findById(id);
        settingsService.delete(settings.getId());
        log.info("SUCCESS: {} deleted.", settings.getId());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(settings.getId() + " deleted successfully.", HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
```

ApiSetvice in the front:

```
delete(id) {
        return axios.delete(`${BASE_URL}/${id}`, ApiService.getAuthHeader());
    }
```

Button in react:

```
<Button
                            variant='primary'
                            onClick={() => {
                                globalProps
                                    .deleteItem()
                                    .then(() => {
                                        table.draw();
                                    })
                                    .catch((e) => {
                                        console.log(e);
                                        this.setState({ error: e.message });
                                        this.setState({ showModalBatch: true });
                                    });
                                this.props.toggleShowDelete();
                            }}
                        >
                            Удалить
                        </Button>
```

DeleteItem:

```
deleteItem = async () => {
        await SettingsApiService.delete(this.state.selectedId);
    };
```

How do I properly handle the oracle exceptions here?

Comment: Spring Data is encapsulating every SqlException in a DataAccessException. You should be able to call getCause() to get the SqlException. Why don't you debug the code and check how the nested exceptions look like

Comment: Try catching Exception instead of DataAccessException